# Волны в CSS или SVG

Tags: html, css, css3, svg

Я пытаюсь создать округлые волны с помощью CSS, и у меня проблемы.
Сейчас я использую `border-radius` для создания волн, но они больше похожи на облака.
Я попытался использовать `transform: translateZ(180deg);`, но цвет div  перевернулся.

Вот что я хочу получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А здесь, что получилось у меня:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.wave1 {
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.wave2 {
  margin-left: -69px;
}

.wave3 {
  margin-left: -69px;
}

.wave4 {
  margin-left: -69px;
}

.waves {
  width: 200%;
  clear: none;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: -150px;
}

.waves div {
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 5px #000;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 70%/100px 100px 0 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.bottom-half {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.background-waves {
  width: 200%;
  clear: none;
  z-index: 50;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 190px;
  margin-left: 75px;
}

.bwave1 {
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.bwave2 {
  margin-left: -69px;
}

.bwave3 {
  margin-left: -69px;
}

.bwave4 {
  margin-left: -69px;
}

.background-waves div {
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 5px #000;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 70%/100px 100px 0 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="waves">
  <div class="wave1"></div>
  <div class="wave2"></div>
  <div class="wave3"></div>
  <div class="wave4"></div>
  <div class="wave5"></div>
</div>
<div class="background-waves">
  <div class="bwave1"></div>
  <div class="bwave2"></div>
  <div class="bwave3"></div>
  <div class="bwave4"></div>
  <div class="bwave5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/44665993/7394871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы предложил использовать встроенный ручной SVG-код.

Ваши фигуры довольно просты, так что волны с элементом SVG `<path>`тоже просто сделать.

Все, что вам нужно знать о `path` SVG есть на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths).

В следующем примере я использовал два элемента пути с [квадратичными кривыми Безье](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves), чтобы сделать волны:

```css
svg{
  background:url('https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8461/8048823381_0fbc2d8efb.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size:cover;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 25">
  <path fill="#9EAFFD" opacity="0.5" d="M0 30 V15 Q30 3 60 15 V30z" />
  <path fill="#9EAFFD" d="M0 30 V12 Q30 17 55 12 T100 11 V30z" />
</svg>
```

Источник: [Waves in CSS or SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44699148/7394871) @web-tiki

Comment: Саша вы координаты с редактора брали ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Ну конечно, если простые полигоны, то можно как-то по клеточкам вручную, но если это сложные кривые, то можно или с генераторов кривых безье https://svg-art.ru/?p=1114 либо в векторном редакторе