# Как сделать волну CSS?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

[image: )]

Как сделать вот такую волну на css? Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/812258/265406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

svg

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 409 258">
  <g transform="translate(322,-15)">
    <path
       d="m -322.03461,15.03086 c 136.09,0.104654 261.811157,1.682384 410.479958,0 L 87.676809,191.16561 C -70.401255,164.1023 -274.10974,300.70108 -321.24928,264.49294 Z"
       style="fill:#0000ef;" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Добрый день! Спасибо за ответ! Не могли бы вы написать где можно было бы с вами пообщаться? Спасибо!

Comment: mans.deity@mail.ru вот пишите - если буду компитентен помогу